# -bash: psql: command not found after manual installation of PostgreSQL

Tags: linux, postgresql

I installed the PostgreSQL database via source code, and I successfully up it and installed the pg admin also. I am able to execute SQL functions via it. But when I type `psql` in the server I am having this error:

```
-bash: psql: command not found
```

Can somebody help me figure out this?

Answer (score 1):

You did the wrong thing. Never install anything using source code unless you are sure for certain you need exactly that and why, and if you were, you'd not asking this here. Resort to package manager for installing software. Even when you use source code, you use it to build your own packages and then install them using standard package manager.

[PostgreSQL packages](https://www.postgresql.org/download/) their most recent versions for all major distributions, so there can not be excuses like "I wanted to run latest version so I built it myself".

Other problem than that you faced with is that now it would be tricky to safely remove or upgrade it. Basically, you don't know where it put its files, so you don't know what to remove/upgrade.

Having said that, it is probably installed under `/usr/local`, and `/usr/local/bin` is not in your `PATH` system variable. So, try to run:

```
/usr/local/bin/psql
```

If that succeeds, congratulations. Otherwise, you'll need to copy and [paste into the question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/728310/edit) exact commands you run to build and install your copy of PostgreSQL so we could figure out how to use that.